# Multi-criteria pandas dataframe exceptions reporting

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

Given the following pandas `df` -

| **Holding Account** | **Entity ID** | **Holding Account Number** | **% Ownership** | **Entity ID %** | **Account # %** | **Ownership Audit Note** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 West Summit Drive LLC (80008660955) | 3423435 | 54353453454 | 100 | 100 | 100 | NaN |
| 110 Goodwill LLC (91928475) | 7653453 | 65464565 | 50 | 50 | 50 | Partial Ownership [50.00%] |
| 1110 Webbers St LLC (14219739) | 1235734 | 12343535 | 100 | 100 | 100 | NaN |
| 120 Goodwill LLC (30271633) | 9572953 | 96839592 | 55 | 55 | 55 | Inactive Client [10.00%] |

**Objective** - I am trying to create an Exceptions Report and only inc. those rows based on the following logic:

1. `% Ownership` =! 100% **OR**
2. (`Ownership Audit Note` == "-") & (`Account # %` **OR** `Entity ID %` ==100%)

**Attempt** - I am able to produce components, which make up my required logic, however can't seem to bring them together:

```
# This gets me rows which meet 1.
df = df[df['% Ownership'].eq(100)==False]

# Something 'like' this would get me 2.
df = df[df['Ownership Audit Note'] == "-"] & df[df['Account # %'|'Entity ID %'] == "None"]
```

I am looking for some hints/tips to help me bring all this together in the most pythonic way.

Comment: Do you need test by `100` in second condition? Or by `None`?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = df[df['% Ownership'].ne(100) | (df['Ownership Audit Note'].eq("-") & (df['Account # %'].eq(100) | df['Entity ID %'].eq(100)))]
```